# Is it possible to call hamlet from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, haskell, yesod, hamlet

I'm trying to implement [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/sweet-tabs-jquery-ajax-css/) nav bar on my Yesod web app.  My question how should I call a hamlet file from the javascript?

```
.....
.....
var Tabs = {
    'Tab one'   : 'pages/page1.html',
    'Tab two'   : 'pages/page2.html',
    'Tab three' : 'pages/page3.html',
    'Tab four'  : 'pages/page4.html'
}
.....
.....
```

As you can see it's calling the html pages with relative pathing, how do I do something like `$(widgetFile "mypage")`?or `@{MyPageControllerR}`?

Comment: why not write data as html? (eg. ul li) some reason?

Comment: of course you can use julius to write that information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you write as html

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="@{...}" ...
```

You can write as javascript using [julius](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates), in that case some like

```
var Tabs = {
    'Tab one'   : '@{MyPageController1R}',
    'Tab two'   : '@{MyPageController2R}',
    'Tab three' : '@{MyPageController3R}',
    'Tab four'  : '@{MyPageController4R}'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out and the second is what I want, delighted that even in javascript we can have type safety!